# gcc compiler error when using certain switches

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello, World" program using gcc in C programming language.  I use the following command on a source code file "test.c" (without the quotes).

I use the following command:

gcc test.c -O -Wall -Werror test

I expect this to compile my program and create and executable called test that I can run the program with from the command line.  However when I compile using the above line I get the following error:

gcc: test: No such file or directory

Any reason as to why this may be?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? Let me know so I can try and ask my question differently next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving the wrong commands to gcc:

do this :

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -O -o test test.c
```

-o is for output

Answer (score 5):

`gcc` is treating `test` as an input file name. Assuming you want to use `test` as the output file name, you need to use the `-o` option.

```
gcc test.c -O -Wall -Werror -o test
                            ^^
```